# Can my wife travel to Europe with me for a break and come back to the UK on a short stay visa?

Tags: visas, uk

My wife has a 6-month visa and I want to take her to Europe for a week holiday. She's been here 2 weeks so has 5 months left before she has to leave the UK. Will she get back in the UK or has she got to stay in the UK?

Comment: Is your wife's visa single entry or multiple entry? That's the key point.

Answer (score 2):

An answer has been posted by our long time user Gayot Fow [on his blog](https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/2017/11/20/uk-6-month-visa-characteristics/):

> Six-month visas, of any form, are uniformly ‘multiple entry’. It means the holder can come and go at any time during the visa’s start/end dates as much as they want and as often as they want.  So the answer here is ‘yes’, that’s fine, your wife can visit Europe and people do this all the time. There is nothing special about it per se.
>
> But take note that the person must undergo a landing interview every time they enter the UK; if the travel pattern raises suspicion (like drug trafficking or human trafficking or some gambit to avoid customs duty), then the Immigration Officer (IO) will start to get worried.  When an IO gets worried, it’s time for YOU to be even more worried.
>
> But otherwise a box-standard visit to the continent is not a big deal.

[CC BY-SA 3.0](https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/about/). Unchanged.